# MVC Sitemap is not working when I deploy it as IIS website

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I have added the MVC SiteMapProvider to the ASP.NET MVC4 App through nuget

Added the sitemap menu & sitemap path html helper in the layout.

When running the web application in Visual Studio Development Server i got the sitemap menu and sitemap path breadcrumb got generated successfully for the links i specified in the Mvc.Sitemap.

But when i try to run the same application in IIS Express or through IIS, Nodes are not getting generated. Just the  generated without any nodes. No errors were thrown. In IIS i run as .net 4.0 integrated.

Any more configuration need to add or need to add any modules in order to run under IIS apart from the configuration generated from nuget in web.config.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not aware of any additional required configuration. We had an issue in beta with integrated mode where it was trying to access HTTPContext at application startup, but that threw an exception. I suggest you open an issue @GitHub, because this will probably take some back and fourth to resolve. Please post your node, routes and web.config configuration. https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you haven't deployed your HTML helper templates. Be sure you copy over the contents of the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` directory to your server.